# How JavaScript variable name link to memory address?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, v8

In C++, `int a=3`, the compiler will compiles variable name `a` to the memory address, just like `int 0x0001=3`.

I'm interested in how JavaScript variable name link to memory address, maybe use `Environment Record`? But `Environment Record` looks like not store memory address.

Comment: JavaScript is a higher-level language than C++. There is no need to concern yourself with how variables are implemented. All that's required of the runtime is that things work according to the specification.

Comment: Also, there is no standard on this. The standard doesn't often say "how" something should be done (internally), only that it should be done. So, it's implementation-specific and whatever answer you might get may not be true for all implementations of the JS runtime.

Comment: "*In C++ the compiler will compiles variable name a to the memory address*" - not quite, that's a simplification already. It might also compile to a register address or to a stack offset, depending on whether the variable is static and how it is used. And then, in JavaScript there is the additional complication that closures capture by reference, not by copy, so many variables need to be allocated on the heap (as part of the environment record structure).

Answer (score 0):

As a (somewhat simplified) mental model, you can assume that a JavaScript engine maintains a set of dictionary objects to implement scope chains. Each variable's name is a key in such a dictionary. Scope dictionaries have a parent for their outer scope.

For example, if you have:

```
// Global code.
var a = 1;

function f1() {
  var b = 2;
}
```

Then somewhere inside the engine there's (conceptually) metadata like this:

```
global_scope = {
  local_variables: {
    "a": 1,
  },
  parent: null,
}
f1_scope = {
  local_variables: {
    "b": 2,
  },
  parent: global_scope,
}
```

And when resolving a variable reference inside `f1`, it'll use a lookup function roughly like:

```
function lookup(variable_name, current_scope) {
  if (variable_name in current_scope.local_variables) {
    return current_scope.local_variables[variable_name];
  }
  if (current_scope.parent === null) return undefined;  // or ReferenceError.
  return lookup(variable_name, current_scope.parent);
}
```

In reality, it's quite a bit more complicated, due to e.g. distinguishing stack-allocated and scope-allocated variables for performance reasons, optimizing compilers and interpreters doing things differently, `let`-bound variables and `with`-scopes and `eval` all requiring special handling, etc., but that's the general idea.

As @Bergi points out in his comment, in C++ the reality is fairly complicated too. `int a = 3` will typically just put `3` into a register, `int* a = new int[1]` compiles to a `malloc` call which returns an address, so the compiler has no idea about the address where that array will be allocated, that's only decided at runtime.